# How to play .avi FILES WITH JMF

Tags: java, jmf, avi

i m doing a project in java i m using **jmf** (media package) for the same.it plays **mpg mp3** files but it can't play .avi files give me some hint.

Comment: I agree with johnbk's answer. You probably missing a codec for it. Your program should write a message to to System.err with the format of the avi file if it cant play it. Can you post that error.

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing the codec the file is encoded with..you can use any open source tools like [this](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en), to find out the codec that is missing.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the software. The avi files are now playing, but without an audio. An error is like this "  Unable to handle format: mpeglayer3, 44100.0 Hz, 0-bit, Stereo, Unsigned, 2400
0.0 frame rate, FrameSize=8 bits"