# How to play flv, mp4, avi format video in JAVA?

Tags: java, jmf

I can play .mpg format video with the Java media framework.
But I can not play all format of video.
When I want to play .AVI format video, the video is play but the sound is not come.
How to play other format such as FLV, mp4, avi?

```
public class MediaPanel extends JPanel
{
public Player mediaPlayer;
public Component video;
public Component controls;
public MediaPanel(URL mediaURl)
{

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Manager.setHint(Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, true);
    try
    {
        //Player
       // this. mediaPlayer.stop();
        //this.mediaPlayer.close();

        mediaPlayer=Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mediaURl);
        //Component
        video=mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
        //Component
        controls=mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();

        if(video!=null)
            add(video,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        if(controls!=null)
            add(controls,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mediaPlayer.start();


    }
    catch(NoPlayerException noPlayerException)
    {
            System.err.println("No media");
    }
    catch(CannotRealizeException cannotRealizeException)
    {
            System.err.println("Could not");
    }
    catch(IOException iOException)
    {
            System.err.println("Error");

    }
}}
```

Comment: You are probably missing a codec.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089997/how-to-play-avi-files-with-jmf

Comment: Consider using http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a [Service Provider Interface](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/extensible/) for the encoding in question.  E.G.  The JMF provides an SPI for MP3 that can be added to the run-time class-path of an app. to allow it to read MP3s using Java Sound.